# jQuery extend() when passing object from an HTML tag's data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing options to an object through an HTML tag's data-options attribute.  The HTML tag looks like this:

```
<div class="js-target" data-options="{'openText':'Simon SaysOpen','closeText':'Simon Says Close','loadingText':'Simon Says Wait'};"></div>
```

The object in the data-options attribute is being added to a default object using jQuery's extend() method.  I am not sure why the Object that is returned is treating each letter as a key value pair.

[image: Image of console]

Here's a Fiddle and my JavaScript:  http://jsfiddle.net/2eQG3/

```
var element = $('.js-target');

(function(ele) {

  var defaults = {
    'isOpen' : false,
    'isItCool' : true,
    'openText' : 'Open',
    'closeText' : 'Close'   
  };

  var opts = ele.data().options;

  console.log(opts);
  console.log(defaults);

  var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
  console.log(settings);

})(element);
```

I would like the settings object to look like this:

```
{
  'isOpen' : false,
  'isItCool' : true,
  'openText' : 'Simon Says Open',
  'closeText' : 'Simon Says CLose',
  'loadingText' : 'Simon Says Wait'
}
```

Comment: you need JSON.parse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is switch quotes and remove `;`:

`<div class="js-target" data-options='{"openText":"Simon SaysOpen","closeText":"Simon Says Close","loadingText":"Simon Says Wait"}'></div>`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eQG3/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Thats because opts is a string you must parse it to a json and replace single quotes to double quotes

Use JSON.parse() to parse it to an object and .replace() to replace the single quotes to make it possible to parse it to a JSON object

```
 var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, JSON.parse(opts.replace(/'/g,'"').replace(';','')));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2eQG3/5/)

Comment: while i agree this fixes the problem, i wonder why it was happening. According to the API, simply making it valid json would have made his code work because when .data pulls data from attributes, it attempts to parse strings that start with `[` and `{` as json.

Comment: Switching to `.data("options")` rather than `.data()` seems to fix it too. looks like a bug maybe?

Comment: i would suggest whenever you are putting object in data-attribute, use JSON.stringify(data) so you will not have to worry about this..

Comment: @KevinB ah i didn't know that data parses strings. The problem might be that the string inside data has single quotes so it's unable to identify that it's an object. or because the **";"** is at the end of the string

Comment: i had fixed the quotes and the semi-colon when i tested, but now i can't recreate it not working with leaving the code alone and only fixing the json. strange. i must have missed something.